# Is there anyway to make Xcode 15's code compare style from Top-Down to Left-Right mode?

Tags: xcode, xcode15

I really hate to compare code in top-down mode like this:
[image]

And The left-right mode is more clear for me to see the exactly change has been made:
[image]

But in Xcode 15's commit window, there seems to be no way to use this left-right mode compare window. Is there any way to move from top-down compare to left-right compare?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to move from top-down compare to left-right compare?

There isn't. (I regard this entire view as deeply flawed in Xcode 15.) But there's a feature that I didn't know about that basically takes its place. Instead of using the commit window, use the Project navigator. Click the little plus-minus icon at the bottom right:

[image]

Now the Project navigator lists only the files that have been changed, and if you click on a file name, you are in the normal file editor and you can open the side-by-side comparison view.